# How to migrate Gitlab CI job logs to object storage (AWS S3)?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In the project I am working we use Gitlab CI as the code repository and pipeline tool for our IaC code (Terraform). The IaC Gitlab pipeline job logs are saved on Gitlab. I would be interested to also send these Gitlab pipeline job logs to object storage (AWS S3). The purpose would be to search in the job logs some specific strings (maybe with AWS Lambda). I found these Gitlab documentation links:

 https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html#configure-a-single-storage-connection-for-all-object-types-consolidated-form

 https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html#full-example-using-the-consolidated-form-and-amazon-s3

I would have some questions:

 1) We have several projects in our Gitlab. Is it possible to select only the jobs logs of specific Gitlab projects to be sent to object storage?

 2) In this configuration example below, if "external_diffs" are not desired to be sent to object storage, should the line containing "external_diffs" be removed?

```
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['artifacts']['bucket'] = 'gitlab-artifacts'
gitlab_rails['object_store']['objects']['external_diffs']['bucket'] = 'gitlab-mr-diffs'
```

3) Is there any additional money cost if pipeline jobs are sent to object storage (AWS S3)?

 4) Is it possible to send each Gitlab project job logs to different S3 buckets? It seems that from the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` configuration example this is not possible.

 5) If one wants to search for specific string (message) in the Gitlab job logs (hundreds of job logs/day), what other options would you have?

 Thank you.